# Is there a way to unset a global git config section in a local git config file?

Tags: git

My `~/.gitconfig` contains this `include` section to inherit from a team-wide config file.

```
[include]
    ~/.gitconfig.team
```

However, I have personal repos where I don't want to inherit from this `.gitconfig.team`.

Is there a way I can override/force unset this section in my personal repos? E.g., something I can add to `.git/config` in `personal_project/`?

I'm interested in a solution where I modify configs in my personal repos instead of my team repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No

Git config includes operate:

> as if its contents had been found at the location of the include directive

[ref](https://github.com/gitster/git/blob/9b25a0b52e09400719366f0a33d0d0da98bbf7b0/Documentation/config.txt#L92)

That means you can't override/remove the include itself, as as soon as it's found the contents of the included file are injected/loaded.

You can of course override the settings it contains in a more specific config file:

```
# ~/.git.config.team
[user]
    name = name
```

Locally, via `git config user.name nic`

```
# /some/project/.git/config
[user]
    name = alias
```

Yielding:

```
/some/project $ git config user.name
alias
/some/project $
```

Comment: @stchangg, I wonder if it's then feasible to create `~/.gitconfig.team` with your team settings and `[include]` it in the local configuration of any repository which requires team settings?

Answer (score 0):

As of git 2.13, you can use [conditional configuration includes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_conditional_includes) in order to achieve what you're asking.

For instance, if you keep your personal repos in a particular directory, you could introduce a git config to override the entries in your team configuration:

```
[include]
    ~/.gitconfig.team
[includeIf "gitdir:personal_project/"]
    ~/.gitconfig.personal
```

Alternatively, if you keep your team repos in a particular directory, you could instead just change your team configuration to use `includeIf` instead of `include`:

```
[includeIf "gitdir:team_project/"]
    ~/.gitconfig.team
```