# Is there a way to disable a global git config locally?

Tags: git, git-config

Say I have a global git config set (and I don't want to unset it)
Is there a way that:

- I can clone a repo with that config unset locally?
- Unset that config locally?

Comment: Set it _locally_ with the default value, that should override the global value. When cloning, use `-c` to override the value with another one.

Comment: [Likely no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205825/is-there-a-way-to-unset-a-global-git-config-section-in-a-local-git-config-file).

Comment: @eftshift0 Could you write an example of that `-c` for future reference. Unfortunately in the current problem I dont have a local default value

Answer (score 1):

If you want your entire `~/.gitconfig` file ignored, you can use the environment variable `GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL` to tell Git not to load it.

E.g.

```
GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL= git clone <URL>
```

will not load any global git config file when running the command.

You can also provide an alternative global config file like this:

```
GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL=/path/to/my-other-gitconfig git clone <URL>
```

After cloning, if you don't want to have to specify `GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL=` every time you run any Git command, you'll have to set the local configuration to what you need, as @eftshift0 said in their comment.